# How do make sharing setting of a custom object be controlled by parent in a look up relationship

Tags: custom-object, sharing, relationships

I created a custom object with a lookup relationship to opportunity. I want the sharing to be same for this custom object with that of opportunity.

Comment: Only Master-Detail support this behavior!

Answer (score 0):

You need change the relationship from Lookup to Master-Detail.